# JQuery Regular expression to accept alphanumeric characters and ' , -

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to get my regular expression to accept certain special characters: `'`, `,` and `-` along with alphanumeric characters. I've had a stab at it but to no avail, and I'm quite new to regex, can anyone help?

Here was my attempt which, surprisingly, didn't work...

```
/^\d+/,\'\-\$/i
```

Comment: This is just JavaScript, not jQuery. (In truth, it could be construed as language-agnostic, to some extent.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
/[0-9a-zA-Z',-]+/
```

if it has to be a full string, you can use

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z',-]+$/
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
/^[\w',-]*$/
```

(assuming you mean ASCII letters, digits and underscore by "alphanumeric").

Answer (score 2):

`\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]`, which is not any alphanumeric character.

```
/^[\w,'-]+$/i
```

should do the trick.

What this is saying:

```
^ - match the start of the line
[ - match any of the following characters (group #1)
    \w - any word (meaning differs depending on locale;
         generally, any letter, number or the `-` character.)
    ,  - a comma
    '  - an apostrophe
    -  - a dash
] - end group #1
+ - one or more times
$ - match the end of the line
/i - set case-insensitivity.
```

Comment: actually, `\w` implies `\d` -- see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) :)